# Android Realm: No results when added in singleton

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm testing out Realm for database storage.

I'm using a singleton for fetching and managing common data that needs to be refreshed fairly often. But it seems that the Realm defaultInstance that get in my singleton is not in the same scope as if I get it in my Activity. So when I fetch remote data via my singleton, then save to realm, I can't retrieve that data from an Activity (get an empty result set).

I have attempted to pass in the Realm instance I defined in the Activity to the singleton (and close it there as well), but I still cannot retrieve saved results via the Activity instance.

I'm setting the default configuration in my Application class if that makes a difference.

Any help would be appreciated in clearing this up.

**Edit

Here's some more code. I'm using retrofit and gson, and my relevant services are in a Utility class (which may be causing the issue).

```
 private void fetchMyObjects(Context context) {

        // Fetch the myObjects
        UtilityServices utilityServices = new UtilityServices(context);
        utilityServices.getMyObjects(new UtilityServices.MyObjectsListener() {
            @Override
            public void gotMyObjects(final ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects, Exception e) {
                if(e == null) {
                    Realm realm = null;
                    try {
                        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                realm.delete(MyObject.class);
                                realm.copyToRealm(myObjects);
                                Log.v("qwer", "LocalDataFragment fetchMyObjects: " + realm.where(MyObject.class).findAll().size());
                            }
                        });
                    } finally {
                        if(realm != null) {
                            realm.close();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // TODO: Handle a myObject error.
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you committing your transactions?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin - Yes, I'll paste in the code I use.

Comment: How exactly are you getting it on the UI thread?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - The exact same method in my Activity, but I'm using realm.where(MyObject.class).findAll()

Comment: No like, are you saving with an AsyncTask, or...?

Comment: For now I'm just doing everything on the UI thread as a proof-of-concept and to minimize unforeseen hangups. Except in this case I seem to have run into one ha ha.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - Or were you referring to how I'm retrieving remote data?

Comment: well I pretty much need *all* code that is relevant to retrieving the data and saving the data and their context.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - updated

Comment: How are you querying the data? I just see adding them

Comment: Try adding a `RealmChangeListener` to your `realm.where(MyObject.class).findAll();`, and you should keep a field reference to this `RealmResults<T>`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - Ok, sorry this example may be confusing, I am actually able to retrieve results with the log query in the example code above. It's only when I attempt to run a query in my Activity that I get no results.

Comment: It is quite likely that, somehow, the `gotMyObjects` method is not running on the UI thread.  This could happen if it is called in an `intentService`, from an `asyncTask`, or an Rx Scheduler.  I suggest you try logging the thread id from the method: `Log.d(TAG, "on thread: " + Thread.currentThread())`

Comment: You are right I think. If I'm interpreting this correctly, I was querying and saving realm data outside of a fragment or activity (in a standalone utility class), and I was not on the UI thread, therefore could not access it inside a fragment or activity. I fixed this by moving these methods to a detached fragment, which seems to be working fine. If someone wants to weigh in on this and post an answer I'll give them credit.

Comment: Sure!!!  I can do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way that the results of a Realm transaction would not be visible after a transaction is executed and that is that the transaction takes place on a different thread.

It seems quite likely that this is the case, in your code, since, if `getMyObjects` ran on the UI thread, you would be getting the "no network activity on the UI thread exception"